# Consume webservice Workflow Foundation 4.5

Tags: web-services, workflow-foundation-4

My solution has 2 projects. One is a workflow service and the other is a webservice. I want to know if I can make the workflow consume the webservice without having to create a custom code activity...

Basically the webservice is a call-and-forget kind of thing... I tried the "send" activity but i couldnt manage to get it working...

i also downloaded the code samples from MSDN but couldnt find a match for my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your webservice is a WCF compatible service you can do an add service reference and the required custom activities will be generated. And if that works you can also configure a standard Send and ReceiveReply to do the same thing. If you are using an ASMX/WSE style web service this usually works but takes a bit more doing to get the message contract right.